# Parse crash reporting 1.9.2 not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to check if my crashes are being successfully send to Parse.com? I've perform a dozen crashes in a real device and its been at least 4 hours and the crash dashboard is still empty. I'm importing ParseCrashReporting then on my app delegate:

```
    //Crash Reporting
    ParseCrashReporting.enable()

    //Parse.com
    Parse.setApplicationId(kAppKey, clientKey: kClientKey)
```

and created the script with

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH 
cd /Users/marcosgriselli/Desktop/Showing/ShowingApp/Showing/cloud
parse symbols -p "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse crash reporting was just recently deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It looks like they haven't taken the time to update their documentation yet, but I received this email from them last Tuesday (November 17th).

### Update to Parse Crash Reporting

> Hi there,
>
> At Parse, we're always working to improve your developer experience.
>   Last December, we launched [Parse Crash Reporting](http://link.parselink.com/c0v02XnY0mvF00ZQp09Cu00) with the goals of
>   recognizing, tracking, and ultimately resolving crashes in your app.
>
> In the time since, we've seen huge strides being made within the
>   industry's native solutions. These native experiences have the
>   advantage of being more tightly integrated into your build and release
>   process, offering a more robust, streamlined, and frictionless
>   development experience for you.
>
> The Parse Crash Reporting tool is now being deprecated in favor of
>   these great native solutions. We will continue supporting Parse Crash
>   Reporting until March 1, 2016.
>
> Here's how you can smoothly switch from Parse Crash Reporting to Apple
>   or Google's offerings:
>
> - [Apple Docs](http://link.parselink.com/R00mv90FXZ0020n0YDQuqv0)
> - [Google Docs](http://link.parselink.com/K00XvYF00muE2rZ9n00v0Q0)
>
> We're constantly tackling new challenges to
>   help you build better than ever before. Please reach out if you have
>   any questions or concerns to [community@parse.com](http://mailto:community@parse.com).
>
> - The Parse Team